# Missing character ⚠ (U+26A0) when using pandoc xelatex engine on a markdown document

Tags: xetex, unicode, pandoc, markdown

I have a markdown document with the ⚠ (U+26A0) symbol in it.

I'm using [pandoc 2.11.3.1](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/2.11.3.1) on Ubuntu 18.04 as this:

```
pandoc -f markdown -t pdf -H preamble.tex -c style.css --pdf-engine=xelatex -o file.pdf file.md
```

Here is the man explaining the options: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html

The file `preamble.tex` contains the following:

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

And I encounter this error:

```
[WARNING] Missing character: There is no ⚠ (U+26A0) in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;!
```

I know that I can use `\danger` from the [fourier](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fourier) package, and it actually works, but I need to generate both an HTML5 page (in that case, the `\danger` is obviously not recognized) out of the markdown document *and* a PDF file, without touching the markdown content itself each time I have to switch the output formats.

How could I use the direct ⚠ symbol so that it is actually rendered in my pdf using pandoc with `--pdf-engine=xelatex`? Is there any font with this symbol included?

Notice: if I omit the `--pdf-engine=xelatex` option, this is the error:

```
Error producing PDF.
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ⚠ (U+26A0)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 ⚠

Try running pandoc with --pdf-engine=xelatex.
```

Here is the content of `file.md`:

```
# Chapter 1    

Hello World ⚠ !
```

Comment: As the error message states, the glyph is not present in the font you are using. Find a font where it is present and this error will no longer occur.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think I found the glyph in Roboto (not sure) and DejaVu Sans (also not sure) when I needed it.

Comment: Correction: found it in the STIX Two Math font, hence had to use it in math mode only.

Answer (score 6):

Is there a particular reason for you to use XeLaTeX? If your document can compile with LuaLaTeX, then this can work (`--pdf-engine=lualatex`).

1. [Install](https://itsfoss.com/install-fonts-ubuntu/) [Noto Color Emoji](https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/emoji/) on your system.
2. Modify your `preamble.tex` as follows:

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{luaotfload.add_fallback
   ("emojifallback",
    {
      "NotoColorEmoji:mode=harf;"
    }
   )}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[
  RawFeature={fallback=emojifallback}
]
```

3. Compile

This gives:
[image]

As @ChristophFrings points out, the glyph is present in Dejavu Sans. Therefore, you can change your preamble to (and compile with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX)

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
```

which gives:
[image]